# Automating calculation of NDVI with rasterio?

Tags: rasterio, python-3, pycharm

I want to automate this code below for other 99 images, the problem that I have is that each image is in its specific folder as it's mentioned in the picture below.

[image]

the images are very big and I want to clip them in a specific area.

Is that possible to make it automatic also ?

```
    import rasterio
import os
from rasterio import plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

os.chdir(r'Z:\New folder\S2\L1C_T29SPR_A003995_20160328T111353_2016-03-28\New folder\CLIP')

band4 = rasterio.open(r'Z:\New folder\S2\L1C_T29SPR_A003995_20160328T111353_2016-03-28\New folder\CLIP\clip_RT_L1C_T29SPR_A003995_20160328T111353_B04.tif') #red
band5 = rasterio.open(r'Z:\New folder\S2\L1C_T29SPR_A003995_20160328T111353_2016-03-28\New folder\CLIP\clip_RT_L1C_T29SPR_A003995_20160328T111353_B08.tif') #nir

plot.show(band5)
band4.dtypes

red = band4.read(1).astype('float32')
nir = band5.read(1).astype('float32')

ndvi=np.where(
    (nir+red)==0.,
    0,
    (nir-red)/(nir+red))
ndvi[:5,:5]

plot.show(ndvi)
plt.colorbar (ndvi) #I have also a problem with colorbar as it didn't show properly
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
path = r'Z:\New folder\S2\L1C_T29SPR_A003995_20160328T111353_2016-03-28\New folder\CLIP\'
dirContents = os.listdir(path)

for file in dirContents:
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        subDir = os.listdir(file)
        # Assuming only two files in each subdirectory, bands 4 and 8 here
        if "B04" in subDir[0]:
            band4 = rasterio.open(subDir[0])
            band5 = rasterio.open(subDir[1])
        else:
            band4 = rasterio.open(subDir[1])
            band5 = rasterio.open(subDir[0])

        red = band4.read(1).astype('float32')
        nir = band5.read(1).astype('float32')

        # And do the rest of your analysis here. NDVI calculation, clipping, etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you be more precise, I'm very new in python.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [rioxarray](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html) for this task.

Here is how I would do it:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import rioxarray


base_folder = Path("Z:\\New folder\\S2\\")

all_folders = base_folder.glob("*")

geometries = [
    {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [[
            [425499.18381405267, 4615331.540546387],
            [425499.18381405267, 4615478.540546387],
            [425526.18381405267, 4615478.540546387],
            [425526.18381405267, 4615331.540546387],
            [425499.18381405267, 4615331.540546387]
        ]]
    }
]



def load_clipped(in_path, in_geometries):
    in_data = rioxarray.open_rasterio(in_path).sel(band=1).astype('float32')
    return in_data.rio.clip(in_geometries)


for folder in all_folders:
    if not folder.is_dir():
        continue
    try:
        red_path = folder.rglob("*_B04.tif")[0]
        base_dir = red_path.parent
        red = load_clipped(red_path, geometries)
        nir = load_clipped(base_dir.glob("*_B08.tif")[0], geometries)
    except IndexError:
        continue

    ndvi = ((nir-red)/(nir+red)).where((nir+red)!=0., 0)
    ndvi.attrs = red.attrs
    ndvi = ndvi.rio.write_crs(red.rio.crs)
    ndvi.rio.to_raster(base_dir.joinpath("ndvi_clipped.tif"))
```